# Microsoft Excel Sum column based on dropdown selection in another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction with regards trying to sum up a column based on a selection in another column.

I have a dropdown box specified which is used multiple times on a page. Within the dropdown there are 10 or so options. What I am trying to achieve is to get the sum of values in another column based on the fact that it was selected in the dropdown box.

```
Col A                           Col B

Selection 1 from dropdown box   4

Selection 2 from dropdown box   1

Selection 1 from dropdown box   3

Selection 3 from dropdown box   1
```

In another cell I would like to show the SUM of Col B where Col A = Selection 1 from dropdown box (answer would be 7).

[image: Screenshot of example worksheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into SUMIF(()

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"Selection 1 from dropdown box",B:B)
```